# Get value from json result

Tags: jquery, json

The json result is

```
[{"Post":{"name":"Name1","text":"Text1"}},
{"Post":{"name":"Name2","text":"Text2"}}]
```

I try

```
var data = $.parseJSON(result) // convert json to object
```

and I try get value follow

```
data.Post.name // give error
// and
data.name // not erro but now show value
```

but not work.

Comment: You Json is incorrect

[{"Post":{"name":"Name1","text":"Text1"}      (missing}),
{"Post":{"name":"Name2","text":"Text2"}          (missing})]

you have missed some }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array, not an object, so you need to iterate though it like so:

```
 $.each(data, function( index, value) {
   alert(value.Post.name);
   alert(value.Post.text);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

`data` is an **array** of objects (note that it begins with `[`, not `{`). You need to refer to an array index on `data`:

```
data[0].Post.name
```